# efficiently insert when statement in explode "sub query"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following column named `data` which is part of a data frame with multiple columns:

```
[{"country": "FR", "createdAt": "Mon, 07 Dec 20 16:35:10 +0000", "id": 1, "stuff": ["a"]}, {"country": "UK", "createdAt": "Mon, 07 Dec 20 16:35:10 +0000", "id": 2, "stuff": ["a", "b"]}, {"country": "DE", "createdAt": "Mon, 07 Dec 20 16:35:10 +0000", "id": 3, "stuff": ["a", "b", "c"]}, {"country": "IT", "createdAt": "Mon, 07 Dec 20 16:35:10 +0000", "id": 4, "stuff": ["b"]}]
```

I want to explode this column named `data` to have a data frame with columns for each key-value pair. There is also a nested array with the `stuff` key which I want to flatten with a conditional statement.

I have the following set of command which is working ok:

```
#reading api response
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json.dumps(response)]))
#first call
df = df.withColumn("data", explode("data")).select(
  col("data")["country"].alias('country'),col("data")["createdAt"].alias('creation'), col("data")["stuff"].alias('stuff'))
#second call
df = df.withColumn("stuff", when(array_contains(df.stuff, "a"),"a")  
                       .otherwise("Other"))
display(df)
```

However I'm wondering if it would be possible to insert the second `WithColumn` statement with the `array_contains` method in the "first call" with the `explode` statement. I feel like it is a bit redundant to have to call the df three time.

Comment: What's your dataframe schema?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this question. I have the first df which contains a array called data. then inside this array there is a second array called ` stuff`. Everything else is string columns. The final df doesn't contains any array.

Comment: Getting your main dataframe and execute this command: `df.printSchema()`. Edit your question by pasting the output command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to put the second `withColumn` statement in the first call because `stuff` column is inside of an array column, so there isn't a way to avoid these two steps (from what I know about Spark).

To reduce method calls you could do:

```py
df = (df
      .selectExpr('inline(data)')
      .select("country", 
              col("createdAt").alias("creation"), 
              "id", 
              when(array_contains("stuff", "a"), "a").otherwise("Other").alias("stuff")))
```

To avoid calling `select` again:

```py
df = (df
      .selectExpr('inline(data)')
      .withColumnRenamed("createdAt", "creation")
      .withColumn("stuff", when(array_contains("stuff", "a"), "a").otherwise("Other").alias("stuff")))
```

Under the hood both options will do the same physical plan and execution